# How can I use the script defer attribute for ASP MVC 4 Bundles with Scripts.Render

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4

I have looked through Google and Stackoverflow and haven't found an answer for this. Is there any built in way to make a bundle execute as deffered or does someone know of an extension helper method that someone wrote to do this?

Comment: What kind of deffered execution you are looking for ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: Explain your app/page specific requirement please

Comment: @kyleb, http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: I just want to defer any scripts that aren't needed for page to load initially. I probably won't use it much but I want to know if there is a way and other people might too searching Google.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try upgrading the Web Optimization to version 1.1.0 on
[Codeplex Site](https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/releases/view/101096) or via [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.1.0)

In version 1.1.0 they included *Element Template Strings*.
So if you want a script tag to contains the defer attribute you can easily do this:

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' defer></script>","~/bundles/jquery")
```

and the following markup will be generated:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: This breaks CDN fallbacks using `CdnFallbackExpression`. The fallback check will be executed before the deferred script is loading causing the fallback to always kick in.

Answer (score 19):

The [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18001995/3481183) is great. I just want to quickly paste my code over here for those who wants to have a  more concise syntax.

Add a new C# class

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="Scripts7.cs" company="Believe">
//   http://believeblog.azurewebsites.net/
// </copyright>
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace MVCExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The scripts.
    /// </summary>
    public static class Scripts
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Render scripts as deferred
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="paths">
        /// The paths.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The <see cref="IHtmlString"/>.
        /// </returns>
        public static IHtmlString RenderDefer(params string[] paths)
        {
            return Scripts.RenderFormat(@"<script src='{0}' defer></script>", paths);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, use Razor syntax:

```
@Scripts.RenderDefer("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Or Webform syntax:

```
<%: Scripts.RenderDefer("~/bundles/jquery") %>
```

Comment: Correct syntax is defer='defer' I think

Comment: That has wider compatibility with older browsers and XHTML parsers. Read more: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: Please explain what does not work for you. Is there an error message?

Comment: Am I missing something or will this cause ambiguity? `Scripts.RenderFormat` won't work because your class is called `Scripts` too. That's easy to fix though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl` :

```
<script src="@(BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jquery"))" defer></script>
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904486/how-can-i-add-defer-attribute-in-the-sitecore-foundation-frameworks-min-js

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I would like to add because I am across almost similar problem where I need to add a data attribute to the bundled scripts (in relation with a GDPR cookie solution).

The solution CookieBot was blocking some of the scripts on Auto-Mode, therefore, I need to implement in Manual mode and mark all of my scripts to be ignored by CookieBot script.

My scripts in BungleConfig.cs looks like this:

```
              bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Bundles/late").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.pep.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jQuery.easing.1.3.js",
                  "~/Content/swiper/js/swiper.js",
                  "~/Scripts/uiActions.js",
                  "~/Scripts/xxm.js",
                  "~/Scripts/addtohomescreen.js",
                  "~/Scripts/d3.min.js"
            ));
```

And, in my _Layout.csthml.

```
  @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script data-cookieconsent='ignore' src='{0}' > </script>", "~/Bundles/late")
```

And, this is what I got after being rendered.

```
<script data-cookieconsent="ignore" src="/nyhed/Bundles/late?v=k3Zae8tC12ZNx0x1iAhyu4U0c8xmGE5TrdLdAqg9C8M1"> </script>
```

Now, the original question, one can add ***defer*** or ***asyn*c** along with or without data attribute.

***Scripts.Render*** and ***scripts.RenderFormat*** both are referenced to ***System.Web.Optimization***, and should be already availabe on MVC project.